# Is my STM32F4 dead?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I was learning things with my STM32F401(CCU6).

I did a motor servo experiment and after that I saw a diode on my STM32 burning. I suspect the servo motor I used is shorted. Now the diode beside the NRST button is burnt and scorched, so I took it off to change to a new diode.

The problem is I realize the soldering pad below where the diode was is damaged. Even the PCB is kinda damaged. Can I still fix it? I appreciate every answer. Thank you very much.

[image: picture of my stm32f4 and the burned diode]

Comment: Dead, sorry to say.

Comment: Ah i see.. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be an easy fix.

Looks like it *was* a Schottky diode from the 5V VBUS pins of the USB-C connector to the linear regulator input and header pins. So you probably shorted one of the "5V" header pins to ground.

So if you replace that part (and any burned-off traces) then it may well work again. The diode connects only to the two 5V VBUS pins on the USB-C connector on one side and to the 2x 5V header pins, regulator input pin and bypass capacitor on the other. You can probe to see if the traces are intact.

The VBUS (5V) pins on the USB-C [connector pinout](https://github.com/yskoht/kicad-USB-C) are the second ones 'in' from each side. The outermost ones are GND and the frame through-holes are outboard of those.

[image]

You can use something like an SMT version of the [1N5819](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/2307181656_HXY-MOSFET-1N5819W_C5451628.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate your assistance..